# Spacing for punctuation after quotation marks

Tags: spacing

Some British style guides recommend that punctuation should go after quotation marks, unless the punctuation is part of the thing being quoted. So you would write

> She said "hello", then waved.

However, if I typeset this in LaTeX it looks kind of bad, with too much space between the quotes and the comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
She said ``hello'', then waved.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps this is because Donald Knuth is American, since my understanding is that American style guides always recommend putting the punctuation inside the quotes instead.

I'm wondering if there's any package that fixes this issue, improving the spacing for punctuation written in this style without needing to manually insert negative space each time.

Comment: For a very quick and dirty solution, especially if it only happens a few times, you could simply have `\!` precede your comma, like so: `She said ``hello''\!, then waved.` Or, you know, play with `\kern` until you like the outcome.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the American Mathematical Society's style guide prefers punctuation outside of the quote (unless the punctuation is logically part of what is being quoted.

Comment: I agree that the British vs. American difference isn't really relevant and I don't really want to get into a discussion of it for that reason.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using LuaTeX then you can add kerning pairs individually using `\directlua`. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
\directlua
  {fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
    {
    name = "kern-qq-comma",   % name of a new font feature
    type = "kern",
    data = {
    ["”"] = { [","] = -150},  % kern between ” and comma reduced
    }
  }
}
\setff{kern-qq-comma}\rm

She said ``hello'', then waved.

\bye
```

Comment: This is truly amazing! Where can I read more about such customizable features?

Comment: Is this the way to go for implementing French punctuation thin unbreakable spaces (i.e., `:`, `?`, `<< ... >>` and `;`) in lua/optex, or is there a ready-made solution?

Answer (score 10):

Since comma is understood as simple text, any method redefining the spacing could be slightly risky and expensive in my opinion. With macros though, we can do it easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \qnc }{ m }{%
  % Stands for `q'uotes a`n'd `c'omma.
  \enquote*{#1}\kern-1.5pt,%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item She said, \enquote*{hello}, then waved.
\item She said, \qnc{hello} then waved.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: 1]

Note that I have used package [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) which has a more productive and style-flexible syntax. It reduces the chance of manual errors. If you prefer the manual method, you can opt for the following code. It's the same code given above, just sans-`csquotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \qnc }{ m }{%
  % Stands for `q'uotes a`n'd `c'omma.
  ``{#1}''\kern-1.5pt,%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item She said, ``hello'', then waved.
\item She said, \qnc{hello} then waved.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. While I understand that you have given a quick and minimal solution, it might be appropriate to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` as `\def` would override the control sequence if it exists. On the other hand, `\newcommand` raises an error suggesting that the command already exists.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily thanks for pointing that out. I don't like `\newcommand` since by default it allows `\par` tokens which is deviant from the original TeX-behavior. In my personal work I had stopped using it long back, but I understand the advantages mentioned by you, so I have now edited the answer and used a more advanced alternative `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse`. This has all the advantages mentioned by you plus a clearer syntax.